# Checking if a string exists within a string and if it does change the letter in that string

Tags: c#, string

I'm creating a hangman game. It's a 2 player game, one player enters a word into a textbox. The word is displayed with question marks.

For example:

The word `Hello` would be displayed as `?????` in the `TextBox`.

The problem that I'm having is how to change the text in the `TextBox` when a player guesses a letter. If the player guesses "H" in the `TextBox`  and enters it, i want the other text to change to `H????`.  How to do that?

Comment: how user is guessing, by entering in same text box or some other control?

Comment: Winforms, WPF, ASP please add a tag.

Comment: The user that is quessing is entering the letter in a different textbox

Comment: Set the texbox to read only and capture key stokes when the window is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following BuildMask() method. When the text changes in the first textbox, add its characters into a hashset, call the BuildMask, then put the result into the second TextBox. If you want to do it case insensitive, you can add an IEqualityComparer in the hashset constructor, you can find solutions for that if you google it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var guessThis = "Hello";
    var letters = new HashSet<char>();

    Console.WriteLine(BuildMask(guessThis, letters));
    letters.Add('l');
    Console.WriteLine(BuildMask(guessThis, letters));
    letters.Add('H');
    Console.WriteLine(BuildMask(guessThis, letters));
}

static string BuildMask(string toGuess, HashSet<char> letters)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var c in toGuess)
    {
        if (letters.Contains(c))
            result.Append(c);
        else
            result.Append('?');
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this complete code

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    { 
       string CurrentString = null;
       string modifiedstring = null;

      public MainWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
       }



    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        string value = textBox.Text.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
        if (null != CurrentString)
        {
            if (CurrentString.Contains(value))
            {
                StringBuilder newstring = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (char c in CurrentString)
                {

                    if (value.ToLower().Equals(c.ToString()))
                    {
                        newstring.Append(value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newstring.Append("?");
                    }
                }
                modifiedstring = newstring.ToString();
                text1.Text = modifiedstring;

            }

        }

    }

    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            var textBox = sender as TextBox;
            string value = textBox.Text.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
            CurrentString = value;
            StringBuilder newstring = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                newstring.Append("?");
            }
            textBox.Text = newstring.ToString();
        }
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please note...here the WPF is something like this

Comment: <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBox Name="text1" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-US" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
            <TextBox Name="text2" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-US" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>